# How do you install zinc strips in a roof without creating leaks?

Tags: roof

[This article](http://www.structuretech1.com/2011/11/zinc-strips-prevent-moss-growth-on-roofs/) gives instructions for installing zinc strips at the ridgeline to inhibit moss.

This picture shows nails through the zinc strip:

[image: Picture of zinc strips]

It looks like they have nailed through the zinc in to the roof. Wouldn't that allow water through the roof?

(Posted for a friend. I don't actually have a roof. :-))

Comment: FWIW, I've been told they don't really work. And, after looking around at roofs with zinc strips, I tend to believe those that have said that...on a lot of roofs I see about 1' of moss-free area next to the strip, but the entirety of the rest of the roof is solid green.

Comment: They don't look like nails they look like Tek screws with neoprene washers. As long as the high side of the flashing is under the ridge(which is doesn't look like it is /;-o ) they won't leak because the neoprene washer seals the screw head to the zinc flashing. [This looks](http://www.structuretech1.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Mossy-roof-after.jpg) like the correct way to install them

Answer (score 3):

Nail them down, the same way your shingles are nailed down. That is, you nail down a course of shingles, then lay down the new course above the last course, working up the roof. This way the next course hides the nails holding down the previous one. At the ridge, before a ridge cap goes on, you also nail down the zinc strips, placed so they will protrude beyond the ridge cap. Finally, the ridge cap goes on. Enough of the zinc protrudes so that the metal gradually leaches out with every rain to impede moss accumulation.

Answer (score 1):

Typically exposed nail heads are covered with roofing tar, epoxy or silicone in order to seal them, though I think woodchips is right in that the nail heads should be under the shingles instead of above.

[image: Nail covered]

Comment: I do agree that some silicon would be of help here. It can also help keep the next course of shingles held down.